# Put color category to a outlook mail

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I can't figure out how to put a category color to a mail using VBA. If I put a color named "Catégorie Rouge" to a mail, if I do :

```
For Each obj In objOutlookfolder
        If obj.Categories <> "Catégorie Rouge" Then
            obj.Categories = "Catégorie Rouge" 
        End If
Next
```

The program works. Executed step by step the program get in the if. If I put a "Catégorie Rouge" category the if works correctly.

The purpose of my program is to use mail body if the mail DOESN'T have any category color. So if the body is read, I want the mail to get a color but I really can't figure out how. In the internet I didn't find anything nor in SO.

Here are my set :

```
 Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set OLNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set Recipient = OLNS.CreateRecipient("example@test.fr") ' You don't need it 
 Set objOutlookfolder = OLNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderInbox).Items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the message. You might also want to make sure you are working with the MailItem object rather than ReportItem or MeetingItem objects:

```
For Each obj In objOutlookfolder
        If (obj.Class = 43) and (obj.Categories <> "Catégorie Rouge") Then
            obj.Categories = "Catégorie Rouge" 
            obj.Save
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that I had to save it